# Stack Exchange data explorer - database connection to Aurora PostgreSQL

Tags: stackexchange-api, stackexchange, dataexplorer

Currently, we are using Stack exchange data explorer(SEDE) UI(integrated in application) to analyze the data and update/delete data through SQL queries. The data which we are using for analysis/update/delete are stored in SQL server.
Now we are migrating to Aurora PostgreSQL database, how we can use Stack exchange data explorer UI for this new database.

Not able to find the option to connect SEDE with aurora postgreSQL.

Comment: You would start by changing the connection string in the web.config https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Web.config  but beyond that you are in for a rough ride as there are plenty of places in the code where queries are used that are in the T-SQL dialect and I doubt those will work in PostgreSQL. SEDE wasn't designed to be database agnostic.